# Only Corner Of Image Link Is Clickable In Bootstrap Responsive View

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm at a loss here. Viewing my image gallery from the desktop everything works like a charm. However when I view it from my phone to test the responsiveness my image links are only clickable in the top right corner. I changed the resolution of my browser(desktop) and got the same results. All of my CSS for the gallery is standard bootstrap CSS.

Here is a visual of the approximate area that I can click in responsive view:

[image: Clickable Area]

And when I inspect my source code my hyperlink covers my image:

[image: Hyperlink area]

[image: Image Area]

And the markup of my image links:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
 <a class="thumbnail" href="http://example.com/h/500/w/800/a/c/thumb/img/gallery/18FT_Wide_Oil_Filters_2014/18_wide_oil_3.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="18FT Wide Oil Filters 2014" data-title="18FT Wide Oil Filters 2014">
  <img class="img-responsive img-protected" src="http://example.com/h/250/w/400/a/c/thumb/img/gallery/18FT_Wide_Oil_Filters_2014/18_wide_oil_3.jpg" alt="18FT Wide Oil Filters 2014">
 </a>
</div>
```

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/sf3LKYHmZb) of my entire gallery page. If you resize the page to where there are only 2 images on each column then you will get the same result I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your this div

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
         <h4 class="page-header"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Wind Tower Hubs 2014</h4>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="col-xs-12 thumb">
             <h4 class="page-header"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> Wind Tower Hubs 2014</h4>
 </div>
```

Comment: It kinda works. On a smaller screen they are not clickable but the layout is broken placing the header next to the images instead of above.